# Overlap feature's style with layer style

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I have a Vector layer, where each feature is created using a image with different rotations.

```
var point = this.__getFeaturePoint();

featureStyle = {
    externalGraphic: this.__getImageURL(),
    graphicHeight: 50,
    graphicWidth: 50,
    graphicXOffset: -25,
    graphicYOffset: -50,
    rotation: this.getAzimuth()
};

feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point, {}, featureStyle);
```

I would like to have a 'select' style so the image URL changes, but the rotation remains.

```
style = new OpenLayers.Style({
    graphicZIndex: 1
});
selectStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
    graphicHeight: 50,
    graphicWidth: 50,
    graphicXOffset: -25,
    graphicYOffset: -50,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    graphicZIndex: 2
});

this.__layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Antennas", {
    renderers: ["SVG"],
    rendererOptions: { zIndexing: true },
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        "default": style,
        "select": selectStyle,
        "highlight": highlightStyle
    })
});
```

It seems that only the feature's style is considered. How can I overlap both styles? Or maybe implement such a styleMap for each feature?